# Looking for unmodified keyboard input from glutKeyboardFunc callback function

Tags: c++, input, callback, glut, modifier

It's been a while since I've used Glut for keyboard input handling, but I feel as though the keyboard callback function once provided an unmodified Key parameter - I might be remembering wrong.

In other words, pressing "r" returned a lowercase "r" character, while pressing SHIFT + "r" still returned a lowercase "r" and not an uppercase "R". This isn't the case now (perhaps it never was) as using a modifier key (SHIFT, CONTROL, ALT) actually modifies the key sent to the callback function. I've been trying to find a way to get the raw, *unmodified* value but have since had no luck.

Is there a way of accessing the unmodified keyboard value from the callback function, or will I need to find a way to reverse the modification manually in order to get the correct key value?

```
glutKeyboardFunc(keyDown);
```

...

```
void Game::keyDown(unsigned char key, int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 'r':
       {
           cout<<"Called when 'r' is pressed"<<endl;
           cout<<"Is NOT called when SHIFT is the modifier"<<endl;
           break;
       }
    case 'R':
        {
            cout<<"Called ONLY when 'r' is pressed with SHIFT"<<endl;
            cout<<"Is NOT called when 'r' is pressed on its own"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    case 18:
        {
            cout<<"Called ONLY when 'r' is pressed with CONTROL"<<endl;
            cout<<"Is NOT called when 'r' is pressed on its own"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this function:

```
int glutGetModifiers(void);
```

You can assign the result to an integer and check it with the following:

```
GLUT_ACTIVE_SHIFT
GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL
GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT
```

A little example

```
int modifier = glutGetModifiers();
    if (modifier == GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL)
        //code
    else
        //code
}
```

Note also that this function should only be called inside the functions that process keyboard or mouse input events.

Comment: I've used that method before, however there's an issue with it in this particular situation. If 'r' = 114 on the ascii table, and holding SHIFT gives me 'R' which is 82, I could theoretically find that holding shift modifies the given letter by 32, and work backwards. But that doesn't work for something like '0' and ')', as the difference between the two is (48 - 41 = ) 7. As well, '1' and '!' is not 7, but 17! In the end, I'd have to have dozens of 'if' statements for each specific scenario which would be somewhat redundant as I could just make a case for each ascii value I'd expect to use